# Whenever I tried to connect nodejs with sql sever getting error as 'Failed to connect to localhost'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have created an nodejs application where I am trying to connect to sql server. But I am getting **Failed to connect to localhost error**

I have enabled TCP/IP connection in Sql server configuration manager.
Also started all services  of Sql server. Still not able to connect.
[ServiceEnabled Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO1ZX.png)

[TCP/IP enabled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnFOF.png)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zH7W.png)

```
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {   
        var sql = require("mssql");
        var config = {
            user: 'sa',
            password: 'password',
            server: 'localhost', 
            database: 'testdb' 
        };
        sql.connect(config, function (err) {    
            if (err) console.log(err);
            var request = new sql.Request();           
            request.query('select * from persons', function (err, recordset) {           
                if (err) console.log(err)
                res.send(recordset);            
            });
        });
    });
    var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
        console.log('Server is running..');
    });
```

Getting Failed to connect to localhost error.

Comment: can you connect with SSMS? with the same user/password/database?

Comment: It's working fine with SSMS. Only issue is with Nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

After some search and youtube videos got to know that I haven't restarted my services.

Watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLcXfRH1YzE) for database connections.

Steps for restarting services (for windows 10):

1. Press Window search key.
2. Type **Services.msc** and enter.
3. You will get [screen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoIuy.png).
4. Make Sure that **SQL Server Agent**, **SQL Server Browser** and **SQL Server instance** that you are using must be start and in running mode. (You can start/stop service from left pane as I have marked in Red on screenshot).

Try Connecting DB with Nodejs.

Happy Coding!!